# Uso da função getline() em C com MinGW

Tags: c, arquivo, gcc, compiladores, mingw

Criei um código para o acervo de uma livraria usando Linux/GNU, e lá está funcionando perfeita. Porém, necessito que o código compile no Windows usando GCC, e queria saber se existe um método para usar esta função ou se existe uma forma simples de substituí-la. Aqui vão os trechos do código envolvidos no questionamento:

```
FILE * arquivo;
Livro * acervo;
int indice = 0, i;    
int ultimo_regnum = 0;

char * linha = NULL;
size_t tamanho = 0;
ssize_t check;

while ((check = getline(&linha, &tamanho, arquivo)) != -1) {
    sscanf(linha, "%[^||]||%[^||]||%[^||]||%[^||]||%[^||]||%hd||%hd||%hd||%d||%f", titulo, editora, autor, genero, encadernacao, &ano, &edicao, &paginas, &regnum, &preco);
    //printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%hd\n%hd\n%hd\n%d\n%f\n", titulo, editora, autor, genero, encadernacao, ano, edicao, paginas, regnum, preco);
    strcpy(acervo[indice].titulo, titulo);
    strcpy(acervo[indice].editora, editora);
    strcpy(acervo[indice].autor, autor);
    strcpy(acervo[indice].genero, genero);
    strcpy(acervo[indice].encadernacao, encadernacao);
    acervo[indice].ano = ano;
    acervo[indice].edicao = edicao;
    acervo[indice].paginas = paginas;
    acervo[indice].regnum = regnum;
    acervo[indice].preco = preco;
    indice++;
    ultimo_regnum = regnum;
    acervo = (Livro *)realloc(acervo, sizeof(Livro) * (indice + 1));
    if (acervo == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao alocar memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

fclose(arquivo);
```

}

Tentei utilizar um #define _GNU_SOURCE porém não funcionou

Comment: No caso parece me que a melhor solução é usar uma das implementações que andam por ai.

Comment: Que implementação seria a melhor nesse caso e como iria ser a composição dela de acordo com as variáveis utilizadas em getline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem duas possibilidades, sendo que em ambas a ideia é utilizar uma das várias implementações da função `getline` que já por ai existem:

- https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229318/6087092
- https://github.com/filosganga/libwurfl/blob/master/src/utils/getline.c

No primeiro cenário você apenas cria a função se tiver a compilar em ambiente windows, testando com `#ifdef` para a macro `_WIN32`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) {
    //resto do código aqui
}

#endif
```

Alternativamente pode simplesmente criar a sua propria função com o código do `getline` e dar-lhe outro nome. Essa nunca irá colidir com uma que já esteja definida:

```
ssize_t obterlinha(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) {
    //resto do código aqui
}
```

Answer (score -3):

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char* string;

string getline(const string msg);

int main() {

string nome = getline("Digite seu nome: ");

int idade = atoi(getline("Digite sua idade: "));

float peso = atof(getline("Digite seu peso: "));

printf("%s - %i - %.2f", nome, idade, peso);

getchar();

free(nome);

return 0;
}

string getline(const string msg) {

printf("%s", msg);

string str = (string) calloc(1, sizeof(char));

if (str == NULL) {

```
printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!");

return NULL;
```

}

int i = 0;

char ch = getchar();

while (ch != '\n') {

```
*(str + i) = ch; //ou str[i] = ch;

i++;

str = (string) realloc(str, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));

if (str == NULL) {

  printf("Erro na realocacao de memoria!");

  return NULL;

}

ch = getchar();
```

}

*(str + i) = '\0'; // ou str[i] = '\0';

return str;

}